# How can i get the data of my PK into one row instead of it appearing several times below each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server and it's populated with data.

I would like to know how can combine them and get the data in one row? As of now, the rows show repeated below each other.

I think the reason why they are below each other is: the PK is the account number, but it has different transaction values for different dates.

For example:

```
Acc#          Transaction value  Transaction Date
------------  -----------------  ----------------
123658421     R2500              25-04-2018
123658421     R5235              23-04-2018
```

This is how I want it to be displayed:

```
Acc#         Transaction1  Transaction2
-----------  ------------  ------------
123658421    R2500         R5235
```

Comment: Search for _dynamic pivot_. There are many questions already.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) seems to have answer of your question.

Comment: @underscore_d  Thanks

Comment: @Sandeep thanks alot